# Spring Boot Profile Override Properties Behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to load an application.yml and application-test.yml. The behaviour that I'm trying to achieve is that I'd like to enable spring cloud only in my production environment, but disable it during the local development. Hence:

**In application.yml**

```
spring.config.import: "optional:vault:, optional:consul:"
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled: true
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled: true
```

**In application-test.yml**

```
spring.config.import: ""
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled: false
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled: false
```

I've tested that my app picks up from application-test.yml. However, there seems to be a weird behaviour, which is that my app still tries to use spring.cloud.consul.config and spring.cloud.vault.kv even though I've run it with SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE="test"

I've checked the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific), and it states that:

```
Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always overriding the non-specific ones.
```

But, if the app still tries to load from spring.cloud does that mean it's not actually overriden?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what happened is that this happens only specific to the property "spring.config.import". What this does is that it automatically tries to load the property "vault" and also "consul".

**Workaround 1**
The workaround I do is that I remove the spring.config.import, since I found out that I don't actually need to import it when using spring.cloud.consul / spring.cloud.vault.

**Workaround 2**
But say I'd still like a different spring.config.import from application.yml and application-specific.yml.There is a good technique, which is to use environment variable as shown [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1877#issuecomment-953558794):

```
some.workaround = configserver:localhost:1337
spring.config.import = ${some.workaround}
```

Issue Reference:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29272